# Vuetify dynamic typography by breakpoint?

Tags: html, vue.js, breakpoints, typography

I am trying to understand the following docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/
Using this vue template snippet:

```
<div class="text-h4 text-xs-body-2">
  FooBar
</div>
```

My idea was that this would render the text in `xs` (mobile) as `body-2` size/style. Otherwise it should fall back to `h4`. However it does not work and I am unsure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base is xs. So h4 is your xs in this example. It says so in the docs:

> These classes can be applied to all breakpoints from xs to xl. When using a base class,.text-{value}, it is inferred to be .text-xs-${value}.

There is no xs in Vuetify, when a breakpoint is omitted that is the xs.

Comment: oh that was confusing I was expected the desktop (md) to be the base